# How to use AngularJS in remote Modal window

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 Page, Person.html and PersonNewEdit.html

In First one we open the second by bootstrap modal window.

Problem: AngularJS not work in second file (PersonNewEdit.Html).

Person.html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="myappCtrl">
    <p>In main page MSG: {{MSG}}</p>

    <!-- Modal window wll display here -->
      <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="NewPerson()">New Person</button>
</div>        

<script type="text/javascript">
    function NewPerson() {
        $("#myModal").find('*').remove();            
        $("#myModal").load("PersonNewEdit.html");
        $("#myModal").modal();
    }

    function CloseModalWindow()
    {
        //we will use this function in Modal pages
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    }

    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    app.controller('myappCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.MSG = "Test";
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and PersonNewEdit.html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Modal window</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Person new edit</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <div id="app2" ng-app="myapp2" ng-controller="myappCtrl2">
                <div>
                    In modal page MSG: {{MSG}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Save();">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var PersonId = 0;
    function Save() {
        //save data to database
        CloseModalWindow();         //Declare this function in Person.html
    }

    var app2 = angular.module('myapp2', []);
    app2.controller('myappCtrl2', function ($scope) {
        $scope.MSG = "Test 2";
    });        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cn trigger the modal from your buttom, did you tried that?  uhm but you should put your modal inside the same html of Person.html
otherwise you can use a library to show modals on angularjs

Comment: second html file will be more and more content and code. For this I prefer separate page into two files. By click on button second file load into myModal div tag by NewPerson function.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs is not included in the second html file. You should also unify those html files, and make it a single app (instead of having 2 separate apps), and have partial views. Because you're declaring the CloseModelWindow in the first file as in-line, you don't have that in the second html. You can create a separate person.js which you include in both files and refer the functions from there.

Comment: there is no problem with CloseModelWindow function, because second file load into first one (in myModal div) and for this reason it not included AngularJS manually, it load before into first one.